# Split string in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ive tried looking everywhere but I just cant see how to do this.
below is a simple line of code im using, however i just want the last 2 digits from "Order".

```
var Order = Range.getCell(1,8).getValue()
Range.getCell(1,4).setValue(Order)
```

I tried .slice() but i cannot get it to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using splice like this:

```
function getLastTwo() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var Order=s.getRange(1, 8).getValue()
  var lastTwo=Order.slice(-2)
  var val=s.getRange(1, 4).setValue(lastTwo)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed works great, although this only seems to work with character strings rather than numbers. Going to try .substr instead.